# How to disable the "d" wrapper in JSON response's in .Net 4

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, json, vb.net

I have a relatively large asp.net app (approximately 1600 web forms, 10% of them being large and/or complex) using .NET 2.0 and I need to upgrade it to .NET 4.0 (and then 4.5, once we drop support for WinXP).

I added a couple of new .NET 4.0 libraries I needed, and worked like a charm; then while testing another forms I noticed that those which use web services where failing because now all AJAX (JSON) request now come wrapped inside a "d" param:

```
{ d: {
        myStatus:'',
        myData: [1, 2, 3],
        myInfo:{a:1, b:false}
    }
}
```

After reading a little about that, I understand that it was a security addition in .NET 3.5, but it is breaking a lot of ours' app forms that use web services. Those web services (web page methods) are in the forms' code behind and look like this:

```
<Services.WebMethod(enableSession:=True)> _
Public Shared Function getSomeData() As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Dim myResponse As New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    myResponse.Add("isOK", true)
    myResponse.Add("howMuch", 37.5)
    myResponse.Add("someList", new String(){"a", "b"})
    Return myResponse
End Function
```

In the "older" code base of my app we called web services using simple calls with httpRequest form browser, latter we begin to use jQuery to make those calls throw the jquery.ajax function, so there is no way we can find every ajax call ("bare" and using jquery) in order to "fix" the response generated in .NET 4, neither change every web service in the app. Until I can solve this I'm stuck with .NET 2.

So, my question is **How to configure my ASP.NET/.NET 4 web app (in web.config?) so that JSON response of web services (which is automatically serialized) wont generate the "d" wrapper but the "old style" data structure?**

Comment: Nice question, I am searched a bit to find a solution, but... no, seems there is not a configuration for override this breaking change. Obviously now you are in trouble, because you will do refactorize every recurrence of .ajax( in your .aspx, .ascx, .js, ect, as recommendend in this article http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/

Comment: Yes I'm in trouble, in part because I didn't upgrade my project when  .Net did... and in part because M$ assumed that every developer used ASP.Net ajax serialization/deserialization :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this help.. adding this converter setup directly after jQuery include to filter json results with "d".

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        converters: {
            "text json": function (str) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(str);
                if (json && json.hasOwnProperty("d")) json = json.d;
                return json;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm afraid that will be my very last option :( Rightnow I don't now how much of the code makes AJAX calls without jQuery (also jQuery is used in a lot of forms in my project).

Comment: ... and three years later I ended doing exactly that: I used `$ajaxSetup` and modified the non-jquery calls (mostly, not sure if I missed any :p) Thanks again!